# Typescript error: jwt.decode is not a function

Tags: typescript, jwt, runtime-error

I wrote the following Typescript code to check out how `jsonwebtoken` works.

```
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import * as fs from "fs";

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("key.pem");
const token = jwt.sign({ foo: "bar" }, privateKey, { algorithm: "RS256" });
const decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
const verified = jwt.verify(token, privateKey);
```

It compiles just fine, but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: jwt.decode is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> ([path]/src/testjwt2.js:30:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v19.1.0
```

If I comment out the line with the `jwt.decode` function, it works.  I tried looking up solutions online and many refer to circular dependencies, mistyped function names, etc.  The code is simple and I used VSCode's code complete function to get `decode`.  So, I'm at a loss as to what's going on here.

Thanks in advance for any help/solution.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it'a a [known bug](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/875). The solution is to change the import line to this:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running in the same error while converting a project to ESM
You can try this.
I checked the `var` with the debugger and the export was missing but in the nested default object. Works for me ;)

`jwt.default.decode(token, { complete: true });`

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the below configuration being available or set in the compilerOptions configuration. If it doesn't break the codes you already had, you can just turn it to false or change the way you are importing the library.
For more clarification you can check this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop.

```
{
   esModuleInterop: true // set it false or remove it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this some more and it seems like the settings in the `TSCONFIG.JSON` file has an effect on how things work.

I deleted a bunch of stuff and this was the bare minimum configuration that made the code work:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",      
  }
}
```

I'm sure this **not** is the correct approach for a production system.  I'm sure I need some of those options.  Just haven't figured out which ones and what combination.